# Issue with alias in TypeScript and Webpack 3

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, module, alias

UPDATE: Solved! Thanks to @JulesRandolph for pointing out the circular dependency issue.

I got a quite stupid-ish situation in the project I am developing at the moment. The project is built around latest version of TypeScript, webpack and awesome-typescript-loader.

The tsconfig contains the following aliases:

```
"paths": {
  "~actions" : [
    "app/actions/index.ts"
  ],
  "~components" : [
    "app/components/index.ts"
  ],
  "~helpers" : [
    "app/helpers/index.ts"
  ],
  "~middlewares" : [
    "app/middlewares/index.ts"
  ],
  "~redux" : [
    "app/redux/index.ts"
  ],
  "~styles/*" : [
    "app/styles/*"
  ],
  "~types" : [
    "app/types/index.ts"
  ]
```

The Webpack aliases config shows like this (please note that i also tried without $ and adapting tsconfig for that usage (with/*)):

```
{
  '~actions$': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/actions/index.ts',
  '~components$': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/components/index.ts',
  '~helpers$': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/helpers/index.ts',
  '~middlewares$': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/middlewares/index.ts',
  '~redux$': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/redux/index.ts',
  '~styles': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/styles',
  '~types$': '/Users/user/Workspace/prj-name/app/types/index.ts'
}
```

My problem is that, **specifically and only for** the "app/redux/app.ts" file, I cannot import using the following syntax:

```
import {
  imp1,
  imp2
} from '~redux';
```

The imports are coming as undefined. I can, however do this:

```
import {
  imp1
} from './[comp-name]';
```

In the other folders I can call using the same syntax (and same folder name). Also, from other folders I can call imports from ~redux.

I tried almost everything I knew and nothing changed.

If anyone is interested, here is the (almost) entire Webpack config: https://pastebin.com/gBabDjH9

Comment: I see no alias nor paths for `~reducers` ... I guess this is the reason

Comment: sorry, reducers was the name of the "redux" folder before i renamed it just to see if that changes anything. Thanks for pointing out, fixing the post now.

Comment: OK
I'm not aware of the sign `$` for webpack aliases ; have you tried while removing those ?

Comment: Yeah. $ means "exact path". Giving the fact that i am targeting a file, it makes sense to match it exactly.

Comment: @bmatei What is in `app/redux/index.ts`?

Comment: @bmatei `undefined` exports could well be caused by circular dependencies.
Does the same bug appears when importing from `./index` ?

Comment: @bmatei you could use [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) on your transpiled sources to check for circular deps. Just run `madge <transpiledFolder> --circular` after install.

Comment: @Louis: It contains "export * from './[comp-name]';" syntax for each file in the folder, excepting "index.ts"

Comment: @JulesRandolph: There are no circular dependencies (i also checked with madge).

Comment: @bmatei OK and you can confirm same behaviour with `import from './index'` ? Also make sure madge is running on modular transpiled files and not in a bundle file ; or use madge webpack plugin.

Comment: @JulesRandolph thank you! Indeed, there is a very nasty circular dependency there. I am quite disappointed since this got undetected by Idea, TypeScript, TSLint and Webpack.

Comment: @bmatei I'm glad I could help :-) I experienced a similar issue few days ago that drove me crazy... until I found madge ;-).
Are you OK if I write an answer you'll accept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact an export is resolved as `undefined` at runtime might well be orthogonal to your webpack config, and instead be caused by circular dependencies.

To inspect this issue, you could

1. confirm the same bug occurs with importing from `./index`. If it does, there is a good chance it's a circular dependency bug.
2. run [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) on your project to identify this circular dep. Something like `madge <myTranspiledFolder> --circular`. Make sure the files madge run onto are modularized (madge supports AMD, CommonJS, and ES6 modules) and not yet bundled.

Comment: Thank you once again, Jules!

Comment: feel free to +1 my answer ;-)

Comment: I'm trying but this is the result:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @bmatei indeed I forgot the "15" reputation threshold ; don't worry :-) Have a good day